# Yii-bootstrap

Tags: x-editable, bootstrap, yii, yii-bootstrap

Что имеем:

1. Использую Yii (первую версию), подключил x-editable как [тут сказано](http://x-editable.demopage.ru/).
2. На странице использую bootstrap третью версию.

Проблемы:

1. При подключении стиля bootstrap в x-editable, требует установки Yii-bootstrap.
2. Yii-bootstrap работает на bootstrap второй версии.
3. Насколько понял, третий bootstrap только в Yii2

Что посоветуете в этой

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрел код x-editable-yii. Там вроде нет зависимостей от пакета Yii-bootstrap. Сами стили могу опираться на то, что на странице подключен bootstrap2. Скорее всего нужно будет адаптировать руками. Или поискать форк под bootstrap3.

Comment: Вот кусок кода из файла "x-editable-yii/Editable.php"

    // bootstrap
    if($form === EditableConfig::FORM_BOOTSTRAP) {
        if (($bootstrap = yii::app()->getComponent('bootstrap'))) {
            $bootstrap->registerCoreCss();
            $bootstrap->registerCoreScripts();
        } else {
            throw new CException('You need to setup Yii-bootstrap extension first.');
        }

Собственно эта ошибка без Yii-bootstrap и выходит. Без этих подключений скрипты ломаются, даже если вручную прописывать.

Сейчас пробую обычный x-editable.

Спасибо за ответ )

Comment: Тут только скрипты и стили подключаются из yii-bootstrap. Этот код можно выпилить.

Точнее, убрать:

    else {
        throw new CException('You need to setup Yii-bootstrap extension first.');
    }

Comment: в общем доделал с обычным x-editable. Проверять с x-editable-yii, удалив эксепшен, нет сил